# Create New XCode Project with same bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

I want to recreate my cordova XCode project by copying files to a new project and using the same app ID and bundle ID. If I do this will all my certificates transfer over? And will I still be able to update my my current app on the App Store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because they are linked by the app identifier so it will work.